# Android USB device mode commands

Tags: android, command, usb, device

Hi 
I am searching for but cannot find any Android USB device mode commands.  I am not looking for host mode in Android, just a device mode commands.  I do not find any in the developer.android site.  Anyone can help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The USB interface is not part of the Android SDK. Custom firmware can manipulate USB, of course, and you can learn more about that at http://source.android.com.